# C++ Does pointer of pointer automatically have access to new value?

Tags: c++, pointers

I am having a hard understanding of how pointers to pointers should work, like in the following example.

let's say I have in a class in a certain file the following

```
typedef object*    objectPtr;
```

and another file containing

```
struct RandomStruct
{
    RandomStruct( objectPtr* obj = NULL ): ojbOwner( obj ) {}
    objectPtr*     objOwner;
}
```

I use both of these as members of another class and construct them like this

```
Constructor():
objectPtrMember( NULL )
, RandomStructMember( &objectPtr ){}
```

I then proceed to update my `objectPtrMember` variable through an editor at runtime to point to an object, and where my logic tells me that `objOwner` would be updated as well, since it points to `objectPtrMember` which was updated through the editor, my editor program says otherwise as `objOwner` stays NULL.

is there something I may understand wrong about pointers ? or am I just not doing the right thing ?

Comment: `&objectPtr`is invalid, *objectPtr* is a type. Out of that to hide a pointer through a *typedef* is a bad idea because a source of problems an a way to make your code less readable : do not do that

Comment: You aren't making clear the distinction between the pointer and what the pointer is pointing at, so it's hard to understand what your concern is. Either one could be updated in different circumstances. What's needed is a complete program, and your description of the output you see vs the output you expected.

Comment: A pointer is just a variable.  A pointer holds an **address** of an object, or the **address** of an array of objects, or holds `nullptr` (or hasn't been initialized and holds garbage and nasal demons, or the object has been deleted and the pointer holds a stale memory address and is effectively a garbage value too with nasal demons -- *here be dragons*).

Comment: A pointer to a pointer is just a pointer, and so obeys all the same rules as any other pointer. A pointer to a pointer variable is just another variable and so obeys all the same rules that any variable does. I suspect you are falling into the pointers are special (in some mysterious way) trap that many newbies fall into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> typedef object*    objectPtr;
> ```

Avoid obfuscating pointer types like this.

> ```
> NULL
> ```

`NULL` shouldn't be used in new C++ programs. It exists for backward compatibility. Use `nullptr` instead.

> my logic tells me that objOwner would be updated as well
>
> is there something I may understand wrong about pointers ?

Yes, there is something wrong in your understanding. Modifying one pointer will not cause another pointer to be modified.

Answer (score 1):

No, when you make a *copy* of a pointer, the value of the copy is independent of the value of the original pointer. e.g.

```
int *p = nullptr;
int *x = p;           // copy p into x
p = &i;               // point p somewhere
assert(x == nullptr); // but x is still nullptr
```

Which is what is happening in your case.

To get the semantics you want, you can make `objOwner` a *reference* to a pointer, like this:

```
objectPointer* & objOwner;
            // ^ reference
```

Now when you modify the pointer that `objOwner` is referring to (assuming the pointer was passed to the constructor of `RandomStruct`), the `objOwner` pointer will be modified as well.